# scylla sstableloader giving error on copying sstables from cassandra to scylla?

Tags: cassandra, scylla

I am using Cassandra 3.0.15v and want to move my data to scylla db 3.3.0v using the sstableloader utility provided by scylla and i have tried different approaches but i am not able to do it.

Table schema is,

```
CREATE TABLE events.test (
    "Id1" text,
    "Id2" text,
    "event" set<text>,
    PRIMARY KEY ("Id1", "Id2")
) 
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ("Id2" ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'ALL'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

The steps that i followed were,

1. took the snapshot of the table.
2. copied it on the scylla server.
3. Run command: sstableloader --nodes serverIP  keySpace/tableName

On running above command the response it get is:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:75  : missing elements...
```

I am not able to understand what am i doing wrong here. So any help would be highly appreciated.

Just found these logs using journalctl _COMM=scylla

```
cql_server - exception while processing connection: std::system_error (error system:32, sendmsg: Broken pipe)
Apr 22 14:54:02 ip-1-0-4-100 scylla[1371]:  [shard 0] cql_server - exception while processing connection: std::system_error (error system:32, sendmsg: Broken pipe)
Apr 22 14:54:02 ip-1-0-4-100 scylla[1371]:  [shard 2] cql_server - exception while processing connection: std::system_error (error system:32, sendmsg: Broken pipe)
Apr 22 15:35:33 ip-1-0-4-100 scylla[1371]:  [shard 3] cql_server - exception while processing connection: std::system_error (error system:32, sendmsg: Broken pipe)
lines 3484-3523/3523 (END)
```

Comment: Can you put more details about error? or check once scylla logs

Comment: added some logs that i found.

Comment: are you using stableloader shipped with Scylla or Cassandra? They are not the same

Comment: @dyasny it's written in the post: "using the sstableloader utility provided by scylla..." :-)

Comment: I would also check if the schema was created in the new cluster previously to running sstableloader.

Comment: yes, the schema was created before running sstableloader.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some minor differences in the table attributes between Cassandra and Scylla. That could be the cause for the error. It requires Minor changes in your Schema

Have you tried following the steps from this Cassandra to Scylla Migration doc?
https://docs.scylladb.com/operating-scylla/procedures/cassandra_to_scylla_migration_process/

Specifically note the schema diff at the bottom of the doc. And also the limitations and known issues.

Another good source is this blog about migration strategies (if you are willing to consider other methods than `sstableloader`), there's also a link there to a webinar on the topic.
https://www.scylladb.com/2019/04/02/spark-file-transfer-and-more-strategies-for-migrating-data-to-and-from-a-cassandra-or-scylla-cluster/

Good luck!

Comment: I looked for differences between the two, I found crc_check_chance is not supported in scylla so i removed it from my schema definition and made a new schema but on describing the new schema the same option is still present there, don't know how? Also i have edited the question and added the schema of my table.

Comment: We don't immediately see a problem in your schema. It might have to do with something else - perhaps hardware or load-realated. I would recommend that you file a github issue https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues.